# What is google developer console and project

Tags: google-drive-api

I need an access to google drive sdk to store and retrive data from web-server but when I tried to get the access, as explained in google drive quick start guide, It says to create project, why is that. and How exactly getting access to drive sdk works?

Answer (score 6):

Google provides a mechanism to allow third party apps to access its APIs. The first step of the process requires you to register the application to Google, eg. so it can bill you for certain access volumes. Your app will be accessing the information, eg the Drive files of end users. They will need to grant permission to your app, so this is a second reason why the app must be registered.

In Google parlance, your app is known as a "Project" and you will "create" (ie. register) your project at the Google Cloud Console.